# Azure MySQL database hung when run SELECT * FROM information_schema.statistics query

Tags: mysql, azure

When I run the

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.statistics
```

query database stopped processing other requests. At that time Azure monitoring display significant growth of "IO Percent" and Network In/Out metrics.

I guess the issue is related to the data size because I see next slow queries

```
SELECT table_name AS TABLE
    , (data_length + index_length) AS Size
FROM information_schema.TABLES;

SELECT tablename
    , count(uid) AS count
FROM sys_log
WHERE (type = 1)
    AND (action = 2)
GROUP BY tablename
ORDER BY tablename ASC;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How many tables do you have?  How much RAM?

Comment: MySQL server is "general-purpose 8 vCore(s)" and database has 570 tables

Comment: try removing "**AS Table**" from your first query `SELECT table_name, (data_length + index_length) AS Size FROM information_schema.TABLES;`  "table" a reserved word